# Magento 2: How to create a custom api and get post json?

Tags: magento2, api

I found many tutorial in the INTERNET but they always use GET method to be a example.

So, my question is how to let API receive post data if the data is JSON format ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/) to create a POST request on Magento API. Just install it, then just make sure you choose "POST" before entering the request URL.

**OT**

If your API need admin or customer token, you MUST obtain a token first. For admin token, the POST request is in /rest/V1/integration/admin/token. While for customer token, the POST request is in /rest/V1/integration/customer/token. Then copy the result(should be sth like "ji0n....") to your POST request. Add a **Header** with key **Authorization** and the value is **Bearer j10n....**.